# Designing a view with an inspector

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm building a new version of an app in SwiftUI and have run into a conundrum.

The scenario is that I have a canvas with multiple objects on it, and I would like to have an inspector view that shows details of the object currently under the pointer. The problem is that my initial implementation makes the whole canvas redraw far too many times.

What I have is a @State variable which the inspector displays, so the inspector view needs to see this state. The object view needs to be able to write to the state variable, so that means that when the pointer comes over an object, it changes the state variable, which then means that both the object (really, the canvas) and the inspector get marked as needing to be redrawn.

What would be nice would be for the object view to be able to write to the state that the inspector needs without invalidating its own view, but I can't work out how to do this in SwiftUI. In the old paradigm, I'd send a message to the inspector, but that doesn't seem to be the way in the declarative paradigm of SwiftUI. I suspect that some sort of observable object may be a solution, but I haven't worked out how to do that.

Related is the behaviour of .onHover, which I am using to generate the mouse entered/mouse exited events like so:

```
.onHover { entered in
    inspectorText = entered ? self.descriptionText : ""
}
```

I seem to get multiple enter/exit events, presumably due to the redrawing, which slows things to a crawl. Is there a better method than using .onHover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that there is a clever way (maybe with `Equatable` views...?) for preventing re-evaluation of the main body, but for what is worth here is a possible solution using a singleton:

```
import SwiftUI

class HoverState: ObservableObject {
    static let shared: HoverState = HoverState()
    @Published var currentItemText: String = ""
}

struct InspectorView: View {
    @ObservedObject var hoverState: HoverState = HoverState.shared
    var body: some View {
        Text(hoverState.currentItemText)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Color.red
                    .onHover { _ in HoverState.shared.currentItemText = "Red" }
                Color.green
                    .onHover { _ in HoverState.shared.currentItemText = "Green" }
                Color.blue
                    .onHover { _ in HoverState.shared.currentItemText = "Blue" }
            }
            .padding()

            InspectorView()
                .frame(width: 100)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

---

This works because only the inspector view declares a dependency to the `hoverState`, which also means of course that if you try to reflect a value (as opposed to just setting the value) in the `ContentView` will not be updated...

Comment: This works pretty well. My actual use case had the inspector divided into a tabbed view, and I found that I couldn't pass down the observed value to a subview, so I had to modify the design to directly get the display value from the observed object in each view. But thank you! It goes back to my initial feeling that passing a message to the inspector object is the right general idea...